# Why in the Temple were the meal offerings that were unleavened, kneaded with warm water?

Tags: chametz-leaven, water, matzah, mincha-meal-offering, kneading-lash

The meal offerings in the Temple (that were unleavened – matzo) were kneaded with lukewarm water [Rambam Maaseh Hakorbonos - Chapter 12
Halocho 21](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1017024/jewish/Chapter-12.htm#footnote75a1017024) despite the fact that this accelerates leavening. We are not worried that they may become leavened because the kohanim are very eager to do their jobs.

Contemporary matzo manufacturers would not dream of letting anything get lukewarm. See quotes from [here](http://www.rakusens.co.uk/faqs.php?answer=8)

> An extra water cooling unit for the ‘mayim’ ‘shelonu’ maintains a
>   constant low temperature for the dough.
>
> An exclusively designed mixer, only used for Passover Matzos, ensures
>   a perfect mix with no flour residue and no heat development on beaters
>   and bowls.
>
> Air-conditioning in the Passover area maintains a low ambient
>   temperature before the Matzos enter the oven.

So why did they use warm water in the Temple?

Comment: When it comes to these things ,halacha says we are not as familiar with exact temperatures and methods,take chalita(boiling) for example Shulchan Aruch does not allow it by flour,by an issur like chametz we are extremely careful nowadays

Comment: It could have simply a matter of comfort. The priests 'on call' had to eat crazy amounts of meat and walk around the the cold stone floor of the temple all night barefoot. Where possible, Maybe they tried to cut themselves a little slack.

Comment: Because nowadays we are overly machmir. And they didn't have AC

Comment: See the Tiferes Yisroel on Mishna 2 in masheches Menuchos,kol hamenuchos,who says its a hidur mitzvah...

Comment: @sam All I can find Tiferes Yisroel to say is ח שכך יפה לפת: - here http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37947&st=&pgnum=191

Comment: @Double AA - I was thinking along those exact same lines -- Yerushalayim's streets weren't wide enough for the ice man's delivery trucks.. wasn't ALL water there lukewarm a few minutes after drawn from the spring?

Comment: @Gary See Pesachim Perek 3 Mishna 4. זה הכלל: תפח תלתוש בצונן The Mishnah here mentions צונן (cold) and the Mishnah Perek 5 Mishna 2 mentions פושרין (lukewarm). I deduce that the פושרין were not at ambient temperature.

Comment: @Avrohom Yitzchok I found the mention of cold water in Chapter 3 Mishna 4 but not the lukewarm in the 5th Chapter Mishna 2(unless I'm getting blinder)--I'm looking at the sacred-texts.com translation.  Is it ordered differently in the English?

Comment: @Gary Sorry I was not clear.
What I meant to say is that there is a mishnah in Pesachim 3:4 (“This is the rule: as soon as dough becomes inflated, let the woman plunge her hand in cold water.”) that mentions cold water and a mishnah in Menachot 5:2 (“All grain offerings must be kneaded with lukewarm water”)
that mentions lukewarm water. 

So both temperatures of water must have been available.

Answer (score 2):

[הרב אביהוד שורץ at Yeshivas Har Etzion](http://www.etzion.org.il/vbm/archive/yomyom/dafyomyomi/2011-05-01.php) on Menochos 53a, writes (in part)

> That the difference between regular matzos and these menachos is that
>   the menachos are kneaded under enclosed conditions which are
>   supervised המקדש הוא מקום תחום ומוגדר, ובו ניתן לפקח באופן מדוייק על
>   כל הנעשה whereas outside the Mikdosh there is a possibility of finding
>   lazy people and therefore cold water is required.
>
> The Chazon Ish (Menachos 55a) cites the opinion of the Ramban that
>   dough kneaded only with oil would not become chometz. Therefore it was
>   necessary to add warm water in order to fulfill the mitzvoh of
>   guarding the matzos against chometz.
>
> From the  Chazon Ish it seems that there are two ways of doing the
>   mitzvoh of guarding the matzos against chometz. One way is the simple
>   way of taking all precautions to avoid chimutz. But there is another
>   way, to deliberately create a danger in order to do the mitzvoh of
>   guarding the matzos against chometz in the best way possible.